# Internal Server Error when querying endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a very simple lambda function that i created in aws. Please see below.

```
import json

print('Loading function')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #1. Parse out query string params
    userChestSize = event['userChestSize']

    print('userChestSize= ' + userChestSize)

    #2. Construct the body of the response object
    transactionResponse = {}
    transactionResponse['userChestSize'] = userChestSize
    transactionResponse['message'] = 'Hello from Lambda'

    #3. Construct http response object
    responseObject = {}
    responseObject['statusCode'] = 200
    responseObject['headers'] = {}
    responseObject['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    responseObject['body'] = json.dumps(transactionResponse)

    #4. Return the response object
    return responseObject
```

Then I created a simple api with GET method. It generated a endpoint link for me to test my lambda. So when i use my link `https://abcdefgh.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/TestStage?userChestSize=30`

I get

> {"message": "Internal server error"}

Cloud Log has the following error

```
'userChestSize': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 7, in lambda_handler
    userChestSize = event['userChestSize']
KeyError: 'userChestSize'
```

What am i doing wrong? I followed the basic instructions to create lambda and api gateway.

Comment: "Internal server error" usually means you need to check the server logs to see what the actual error is. Please check the function's output in CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: @MarkB I just updated the question with cloudwatch log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event['userChestSize']` does not exist. I suggest logging the entire `event` object so you can see what is actually in the event.

Comment: By logging do you mean print[event] ? Sorry if my question is silly

Comment: yeah, do a print(event) to see what's in it

Comment: @Dinero yes, just do some basic debugging to see what is in the `event`. Python is telling you that there is not a key named `userChestSize` in the event. Maybe it's `event['params']['userChestSize']` or something, simply printing out the event object will show you what you need to do.

Comment: Where can i get list of all possible event types like params,queryString etc i mean it could be event['anything']

Comment: You could see some examples in the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-services.html but logging the event will show you what it is, that's the easiest way to see what you need to change your code to handle.